# Files disappearing from Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3

Here are links to four files that I uploaded in the last week, but have now disappeared from my bucket on S3:

```
https://gh-resource.s3.amazonaws.com/ghImage/SWjqzgXy9rGCYvpRF-naypyidaw.jpg
https://gh-resource.s3.amazonaws.com/ghImage/SWjqzgXy9rGCYvpRF-london.jpg
https://gh-resource.s3.amazonaws.com/ghImage/SWjqzgXy9rGCYvpRF-brussels.jpg
https://s3.amazonaws.com/gh-resource/ghImage/SWjqzgXy9rGCYvpRF-ottawa.jpg
```

I know they successfully uploaded because I saw them on my website multiple times before they disappeared.  The last file above (ottawa), I just now re-uploaded, so that I could look at the permissions and see if there was an expiry date or expiry rule.  When I looked at the permissions, 'everyone' has read/download permission.  Expiry date is None, expiry rule is N/A.  This has been happening regularly for the last year or so.  What could be causing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should enable logging on your bucket. This will tell you who/what is deleting your files.

See: [Logging Amazon S3 API Calls By Using AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html)

I found that if you have an expiry policy setup you'll also see that in the logs. See [Lifecycle and Other Bucket Configurations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html#lifecycle-and-other-bucket-config) for more info.

Comment: Thanks very much, George.  I didn't even know that was possible.  I have done it and now I will keep a close watch on it.  I'll update this thread when I know more.

Comment: This was a great answer, b/c it made me look at the whole problem very logically.  Of course, the files weren't just disappearing, somebody was deleting them.  And knowing I was the only one with access to them, I realized it had to be my code.  Sure enough, there was a function that I wrote a long time ago that I meant to go back and fix -- and it was the culprit.  Thanks again for the logging tip, also!